# This query takes anywhere from 1 - 30 seconds depending on server load... How can it be optimized?

Tags: mysql, optimization

```
SELECT id FROM watch_list WHERE item_id = '16837' AND user_id = '2582' LIMIT 1;
# Time: 171025 20:41:38
# User@Host: dylanw68_actmgr[dylanw68_actmgr] @ localhost []  Id: 70246342
# Schema: dylanw68_tauction2  Last_errno: 0  Killed: 0
# Query_time: 1.268647  Lock_time: 0.000031  Rows_sent: 0  Rows_examined: 14760  Rows_affected: 0
# Bytes_sent: 91
SET timestamp=1508982098;
```

Each row only has 4 values so I am really confused on why this simple query takes so long.

Comment: You have this tagged as sql server and mysql, which are you using?

Comment: mysql, didnt mean to tag both

Comment: What indexes do you have on the table?

Comment: Have you looked at the query execution plan?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that `id` is the PRIMARY KEY of the `watch_list` table, the following should make the query very fast.

```
ALTER TABLE `watch_list`
ADD INDEX `AppropriateIndexName` (`item_id`,`user_id`)
```